Cannot access a private class even using a friend class
I am learning C++ and game design using comp4300. In the assignment 2 of the class, the instructor uses a friend class to access the entity class, but I am not able to do that and I get an error:

entity::entity cannot access private member declared in class "Entity"

Entity.h
#pragma once
#include "component.h"
#include <memory>
#include <string>

class Entity
{
friend class EntityManager;
private:
    
    bool m_active = true;
    size_t m_id = 0;
    std::string m_tag = "Default";

    Entity(const size_t id, const std::string& tag);

public:

    std::shared_ptr<CTransform> cTransform;
    std::shared_ptr<CShape> cShape;
    std::shared_ptr<CCollision> cCollision;
    std::shared_ptr<CScore> cScore;
    std::shared_ptr<CLifespan> cLifespan;
    std::shared_ptr<CInput> cInput;

    bool isActive() const;
    const std::string& tag() const;
    const size_t id() const;
    void destroy();
};

EntityManager.h
#pragma once
#include "entity.h"
#include <vector>
#include <map>

typedef std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Entity> > EntityVec;
typedef std::map<std::string, EntityVec> EntityMap;

class EntityManager
{
    EntityVec m_entities;
    EntityMap m_entityMap;
    EntityVec m_toAdd;
    size_t    m_totalEntities{ 0 };

public:

    EntityManager();
    
    std::shared_ptr<Entity> addEntity(const std::string& tag);
    void update();

    EntityVec& getEntities();
    EntityVec& getEntities(std::string& tag);

};

EntityManager.cpp
#include "entitymanager.h"

EntityManager::EntityManager()
    :m_totalEntities(0)
{

}

std::shared_ptr<Entity> EntityManager::addEntity(const std::string& tag)
{
    auto e = std::make_shared<Entity>(m_totalEntities++, tag);
    m_toAdd.push_back(e);
    return e;   
}

I tried everything but it's just not working.

This has nothing to do with C.  C and C++ are completely separate languages.

EntityManager is not the one trying to directly access the private Entity constructor, which is why making it a friend doesn't work.  std::make_shared() (or more accurately, an internal type that represents the control block of std::shared_ptr) is the one trying to access the Entity constructor, so that type is what needs to be made a friend instead.
Otherwise, you should change your Entity class so it can create instances of itself (ie, via a static method that returns a shared_ptr) so it can use its own private constructor, instead of letting EntityManager create them.

Or Create a private function, like, std::shared_ptr<Entity> Entity::make(...) and call that from EntityManager
